# Parsing in Java - unexpected quotes

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I'm trying to understand a piece of code. I didn't write it, I'm just trying to make it work.

It's meant to transform a `.csv` file.
The code is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*;

public class StockParser 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/cloudera/Desktop/training.csv"));

    String [] nextLine;
    String [] previousLine;
    String [] headernew = new String [reader.readNext().length +1];
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/home/cloudera/Desktop/final.csv"), ',');
    nextLine = reader.readNext();
    for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length;i++)
    {
        headernew[i] = nextLine[i];
    }
    headernew[headernew.length-1] = "action";
    writer.writeNext(headernew);
    previousLine = reader.readNext();
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
    {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + " etc...");
        headernew = new String [nextLine.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < headernew.length-1;i++)
        {
            headernew[i] = nextLine[i];
        }
        if (Double.parseDouble(previousLine[4]) < Double.parseDouble(nextLine[4]))
        {
            headernew[headernew.length-1] = "SELL";
        } 
        else 
        {
            headernew[headernew.length-1] = "BUY";
        }
        writer.writeNext(headernew);
        previousLine = nextLine;
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    }


}
```

It works generally, but there's a problem: the input file's first line is

> Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close

followed by lines like

> 59.30,60.05,58.88,59.41,3373800,59.41

The output file should have the same first line, + `action`, and then similar lines, + `BUY` or `SELL`, but when I run this code, it somehow loses the

> Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close,action

line, 
and the next lines look like

> "59.64","60.26","58.88","59.83","3069100","59.83","BUY"

Where did the quotes come from, and what should I do to get rid of them?

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger? And as an experienced user you should realize that at least one core part is missing: the values are written by the CSVWriter; and without the source for that, how should we know what is going on ?
(guessing: the CSV writer doesn't recognize the numbers as numbers, but as strings, therefore it puts "" around them; or the other way round, the CSVWriter wants to make sure that any number shows up as string in the output). Your code, you tell us.

Comment: @EddyG, I ran it in Eclipse. I am more or less experienced generally, but this is one of my first ever experiences of dealing with Java code.
As for `CSVWriter`, that's actually a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to:

> Where did the quotes come from, and what should I do to get rid of
>   them?

The constructor described in the [documentation of CSVWriter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#CSVWriter%28java.io.Writer,%20char,%20char%29) allows specifying a quote-character. Try the following:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/home/cloudera/Desktop/final.csv"), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

The last parameter should suppress all quoting characters.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you simply, use

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(
            "/home/cloudera/Desktop/final.csv"), ',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

But there are few more issues with your code which I tried to correct making my assumptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
            "training.csv"));

    String[] nextLine;
    String[] previousLine;
    nextLine = reader.readNext();
    String[] headernew = new String[nextLine.length + 1];
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(
            "final.csv"), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
        headernew[i] = nextLine[i];
    }
    headernew[headernew.length - 1] = "action";
    writer.writeNext(headernew);
    previousLine = reader.readNext();
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + " etc...");
        headernew = new String[nextLine.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < headernew.length - 1; i++) {
            headernew[i] = nextLine[i];
        }
        if (Double.parseDouble(previousLine[4]) < Double
                .parseDouble(nextLine[4])) {
            headernew[headernew.length - 1] = "SELL";
        } else {
            headernew[headernew.length - 1] = "BUY";
        }
        writer.writeNext(headernew);
        previousLine = nextLine;
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, EddyG suggested the right direction for finding the problem. The `opencsv` jar has `Class CSVWriter`, and it has a different constructor variants, among which is `public CSVWriter(Writer writer,char separator,char quotechar)`. Fiddling with `quotechar` improved things.
Source: [opencsv documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html)